# JavaFX - Set bounds in LineChart

Tags: java, javafx, charts

I created a lineChart with varying bounds for the X axis and would like to modify the X axis bounds so these will fit what I want. I've tried using `xAxis.setLowerBounds()` but hasn't worked yet.

[image: The chart I'm getting as a result]

Here's the code:

```
public static LineChart envolventeMultiple(){

    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(), yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Distance (m)");
    xAxis.setLowerBound(Utils.getXIni() - 1);
    yAxis.setLabel("Deformation(mm)");
    LineChart chart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis);

    chart.setData(getChartData());
    chart.setTitle("Envolvente");

    chart.setCreateSymbols(false);


    return chart;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the problem was with `setAutoRanging()`, which is by default set to `true` so the new bounds were never set. This line of code fixed it:

```
xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
```